Problems adding C# icon resource in VS 2022 error MSB3554 'Could not find a part of the path....'
I can add an icon through Resources.resx and the icons are placed in the Resources folder, but when it compiles I get MSB3554 and another error without a reference code. Both errors are "Could not find a part of the path...." The problem appears to be that an extra 'Properties' folder is inserted in the path.
When the path should be
...\VS\Project\Project\Resources\icon.ico,
it is
...VS\Project\Project\Properties\Resources\icon.ico.
If I move the Resources folder under Properties to match the path given in the error when it compiles the new path error is
...VS\Project\Project\Properties\Properties\Resources\icon.ico
Note that this is a Windows Forms app and I'm migrating my code from .Net Framework to .Net 8.0. Because of a large warning list I created a new project and copied my source files into the new project - not overwriting the new VS generated project files.
I've tried setting "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" and the .ico file path is correct in the file properties.
Any ideas?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When I tried to add the .ico file, I did get the error you mentioned after building:

According to the error message, I copied and pasted the Resources folder to the Properties folder and tried to build again, and it was able to see that the project was built successfully:

I suggest you try the above behavior again to see if it works. I think this is a VS issue. If you still encounter this issue after trying it, you can report this issue to DC. There are many VS developers who can help you.

Thanks for looking at it Cody. I posted it to DC - there's a similar unresolved thread posted a couple weeks ago. I spent a few hours on it yesterday and it's something I can comment out and avoid for a few weeks.

OK, if you report the issue in DC, please provide a link where you submit the issue on DC, so that people with the same problem can find a solution more quickly in the future.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Resourcesresx-Error:-Cant-import-an-ic/10789534#T-ND10802104

Thanks for the feedback! Issues with more upvotes on the Developer Community tend to attract greater attention from the dev team, which might help expedite a resolution.
